# How to describe-mode (but not the current major mode)?

Tags: major-mode, help

I know that `describe-mode` will describe the *current* major mode. Is it possible to describe a mode, and I will input the mode name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `describe-function` by typing `C-h f` and, when asked for the function, type the name of the mode which is itself a function.

Comment: That will describe the function which will load the mode, not the mode.

Comment: try it! @Muihlinn

Comment: Yes. The value of variable `major-mode` is the symbol bound to the function that turns a major mode on - so `describe-function` for that function describes the major mode. The value of variable `mode-name` is the string naming the mode, which you see in the mode-line.

Comment: It doesn't describe nothing more than the function itself in my setup, at least with the modes I tried before posting first comment, as they came to mind. Those could be extremely quiet in their ouptut, but definately not what I get when I ask `C-h m` from a buffer.

Comment: I get a description of what the mode is for followed by a complete list of key bindings

Comment: @AidanSchofield I should dig why I don't.

Comment: @Muihlinn `C-h m` is describing *all* the modes (major and minor) enabled in a *particular buffer*.  The only part of that output which is pertinent to the major mode (or indeed any one of the minor modes; notwithstanding my comment to db48x's answer) is the same as you get with `describe-mode`.  If you still think you're seeing something wrong, you'll need to provide an example and tell us how to replicate it.

Comment: @phils For example, `C-h f` `web-mode` is very short (just the function docstring) and doesn't bring up any keybinding **unless** I've loaded it before. Same with a few other I tried, but can't remember now.

Comment: @Muihlinn If you haven't loaded the library then the keymap doesn't exist -- there *are* no keybindings until it's been loaded.  The docstring is part of the autoload declaration, so it can still show you the text of that, but it can't show you things which haven't been loaded.

Comment: @phils so my first comment, with some clarification, was true (or mostly).

Comment: @Muihlinn Well your first comment ("That will describe the function which will load the mode, not the mode") implied that a mode is not the same thing as the function by that name, when (with the exception of a very small number of minor modes), the `foo-mode` mode *is* the `foo-mode` function; so no, I still don't agree with that.  The sense in which it's accurate is that an *autoload* declaration for a function *is* a distinct object; however if you are seeing the autoload then there is no way to describe the (not yet loaded) mode beyond what the autoloads say, so it's a fairly moot point.

Comment: The important difference between using `C-h m` and `C-h f` to read about a particular mode is that when you use the former the library in question is guaranteed to have been loaded already.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `describe-minor-mode` to get help on any minor mode. It prompts you to enter either a symbol or an indicator from your mode line, and gives you the help for that mode. I don't think that there's anying similar for major modes.

Comment: This generally calls `describe-function`.  In cases where the minor mode is just a variable (being acted on without a mode function being involved), then it will call `describe-variable` instead.  Major modes *always* have a function, so there is no need for anything more than `describe-function`.